# Button with colored background

Tags: go, fyne

I am using fyne. I am working on a game (with buttons obviously). I would like to know if there is a way to change button's background? I know there is button with image instead of text, but I would only like to change background color of button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fyne widget APIs are based on meaning rather than graphics, which makes two potential answers.
You can mark a button as high importance (`Button.Importance = widget.HighImportance`) which will show as a primary colour.

If your application wishes to control colour then the way you do it is to place a background rectangle *under* the button, which will show through (e.g. as `container.NewMax(canvas.NewRectangle(bgColor), button)`).

Comment: That is very clever, yes it works, thank you